# Deleting multiple duplicate rows

Tags: sql, hive, count

This code I have finds duplicate rows in a table. H

```
SELECT position, name, count(*) as cnt
FROM team
GROUP BY position, name,
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

How do I delete the duplicate rows that I have found in Hiveql?

Comment: Quick google search: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-delete-duplicate-rows/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from `distinct`, you can use `row_number` for this in Hive. Explicit `delete` and `update` can only be performed on tables that support ACID. So `insert overwrite` is more universal.

```
insert overwrite table team 
select position, name, other1, other2...
from (
    select
        *,
        row_number() over(partition by position, name order by rand()) as rn
    from team 
) tmp
where rn = 1
;
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try this.assuming id is primary key column

```
delete from team where id in (
select t1.id from team t1,
(SELECT position, name, count(*) as cnt ,max(id) as id1
FROM team
GROUP BY position, name,
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) t2
where t1.position=t2.position
and t1.name=t2.name
and t1.id<>t2.id1)
```

Comment: thanks for answering... the id is not a primary key unfortunately

Answer (score 2):

This is an alternative way, since deletes are expensive in Hive

```
 Create table Team_new
 As
  Select distinct <col1>, <col2>,...
  from Team;

Drop table Team purge;

Alter table Team_new rename to Team;
```

This is assuming you don’t have an id column. If you have an id column then the 1st query would change slightly as

```
Create table Team_new 
As
 Select <col1>,<col2>,...,max(id) as id from Team
 Group by <col1>,<col2>,... ;
```

Other queries (drop & alter post this) would remain the same as above.